# Imported OBJ will not move to grid

Tags: objects, obj

I imported an OBJ from SweetHome3D to the latest version of Blender. When every object is selected (press A), I press "shift-S" to click "Selection -> To Grid". However, the single OBJ object will not move to the grid. I already have my camera positioned for the grid. I have never dealt with OBJ files; can I not move them?

Below is my car after applying SteveW's suggestion. The car is on the central grid (what ever you may call it), but it is broken. The grid is at the orange dot.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more detailed explanation. :)

Comment: @SteveW, Nice work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After import, try this:

[image]

The object should appear in the center of your grid.

**Update:**

Note: The default Grid Floor (visible grid) is merely a 2D representation of a very small part of the actual grid, centered at the zero point (X=0, Y=0, Z=0).

When you *Shift S* > *Selection to Grid*, the selected object's origin ('center' point) will snap to the nearest grid division (a position in 3D space where all three (X,Y and Z) grid lines intersect). The object geometry (the visible object), will move with the origin, maintaining its position relative to the origin.

By default, the origin is normally in the center of an object. It is the rotation point and location, displayed here:

[image]

The geometry, and origin, of an object can be moved independently of each other, and this can be confusing because the origin gives you the location of the object, but the visible object (geometry) can be in a different location!

In your case, the imported .obj objects were not near the Grid Floor and Blender had no information about an origin, so it placed origins for all the objects at the zero point (which happens to be one of the points where all three grid lines intersect). And then, of course, with *Shift S* > *Selection to Grid*, nothing happened.

ideasman42 suggested: '*Origin to Geometry*, then snap the objects to the grid', which works - but they were still not where you wanted them because they would have snapped to the nearest grid division. At this point, instead of *Shift S* > *Selection to Grid*, you could have used *Shift S* > *Selection to Cursor* (assuming the 3D Cursor was in the center).

According to what you said, I thought you only had one object, and so I suggested you use: *Origin* > *Geometry to Origin*, which would have worked perfectly but…  :)

I hope this clarifies things a bit and isn't too confusing.

Comment: This works! However, the cars wheels and interior look like they have been in an accident (OoO), but technically I never asked how to move it in one functional piece. Therefore, this is the answer (^u^)!

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson to move it in "one functional piece" use *Origin to Geometry* instead.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson, This answer was purely to get your object to the center of your grid in the simplest way, as you seemed to be unaware of the '3D grid'. - ideasman42's answer (although correct), would have left the object in some place other than the grid center, and it appears you were having trouble finding it.

Comment: Not sure this is the correct answer? - or its answering a different question, `Origin to Geometry` has nothing to do with the grid.

Comment: @ideasman42, can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

Because its already snapped to the grid.

To explain: OBJ is a mesh-only format, therefor there is no object center. Just geometry and the object center is always (0, 0, 0), so there is no snapping to do.

To do what I *think* you're asking, you can have blender calculate a new origin (in the toolbox `Origin -> Origin to Geometry`), then you can snap the objects to the grid.

You may also want to split the mesh by loose parts before doing this though OBJ may be already split up, depending on the import options.

Comment: How is it already snapped to the grid? I may import a single piece of furniture and it would be very far away from the grid

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson "OBJ is a mesh-only format, therefore there is no object center ... the object center is always (0, 0, 0), so there is no snapping to do."

Comment: The OBJ object is not on my grid like I want it to be. I must zoom out and try to find the object. Once I find the imported object, it will not move. It is stuck. How do I force it to go to the grid?

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson by 'grid' do you mean the visible grid in the 3D View? - 'Selection to Grid' snaps the object to the nearest grid node in 3D space, and can be anywhere.

Comment: @SteveW, Yes, I mean the visible grid. I never heard of grid nodes.

Comment: @SteveW, Nodes is a confusing term here, I think `Object Center Point` is the correct term.

Comment: Nodes is not my term, if you see the tool tip for Snap >Selection to Grid, it says 'Snap selected item(s) to nearest grid node'.

Comment: @SteveW, renamed `grid node` -> `grid division` r58703.